# Is it possible to update in database in jdbccursoritemreader

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am using Spring batch JDBCCursorItemReader to read set of data from a table. Once data is read spring batch will process each row in a chunk(reader, processor, writer). Now I want to update/delete those records which my reader fetched to avoid reprocessing by another instance of same job. Can someone please tell me how can I do this in reader?

Thanks

Comment: You don't do that in the reader, that is only for reading... You want to do that in your writer of maybe a custom chunk listener.

Comment: But I want to update/delete as soon as my reader fetch those records, not after processing, as writer will get executed only after processing can I use writer for this?

Comment: And what are you going to do when the operation fails? Your record is already marked as processed while it isn't... Then what? Also it will only be visible after the transaction committed and you don't want a transaction per record as that would kill your performance. Wouldn't it be easier solved by not allowing multiple instances of the job?

Comment: Thanks for reply.As per my requirement I need to run multiple instance of same job, so I want to update the input rows to intermediate state, which will not be processed by other instance. If step/job fails I will update back to initial state so it will be reprocessed by other instance. If I use chunk listener can I get all record read by itemreader at once to update to intermediate state?

Comment: Why are you running multiple instances of the same job to process the same data at the same time?  There are better ways to orchestrate the parallel processing of data within a single job instance that prevent this type of issue (partitioning, etc).

Comment: I am already using partition logic. As new records will be keep getting inserted to this table I need to run the job every 1 minute or so to process new records, but if the earlier instance is not finished yet then the second instance of the job pickup the same records which are taken by first instance as well. That's why I need to update those records which are picked up by first instance before processing(as each record processing takes quite sometime) , so that when new instance (2nd) of job triggered it won't fetch those records based on some flags. Thanks.

Comment: @springenthusiast Did you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Like it has been pointed out this might be a **bad design** idea. However if your sure this is what you want to do,

create a two step job,
step a, with commit interval as 1
 Read the record
 Write the updated record with the current job execution id
step b
 Read the record where job execution id is current job execution id
 process and update as needed

Notes

1. I do not recommend this approach for reasons stated in the comments
2. A commit interval of 1 would **kill you performance wise** so this approach if ever used should be for a low volume job only.

Comment: Couldn't understand what you mean 2 step process? I want to update those records which got fetched by my itemreader to something like processing as soon as first time itemreader gets executed, so it will not be picked by other instance. Like when I execute 'select * from tablea where status="not processed"', will give 100 rows(all these rows needs to be updated to processing before start of processing),in mean time if 100 more rows are inserted to tablea with status="not processed" second instance of table should pick only 100 records, not 200 or 100+ when the first instance still running.

Comment: I understand what your looking for. You can **not** do it in the available item writer. You will need to write a customer item writer.

OR

You can write a 2 step job.

Step 1 in the job Reads the Record and Marks the Record as read to process.

Step 2 reads only those record that are marked as ready to process and then process those records